# Regexs to split address and return specific parts

Tags: c#, regex

I'm after a RegEx for C# to break up an address into specific parts, and return those parts, splitting based on a patter.

A unit number can be defined as any combinations of numbers and a single letter, or any combinations of number, space and a single letter

> i.e. 2a, 328b, 32 c are all unit numbers.

If I have an address - eg.

> ```
> unit 32 a Smith Crescent, Johnsonville
> ```

I want Regexs that allow me to either return everything up to and including the last instance of a unit number

> unit 32 a

OR everything after and not including the last instance of a unit number

> Smith Crescent, Johnsonville

another (unrealistic) example:

```
unit 32a Smith 3 d Crescent, Johnsonville
```

I want to be able to get either:

```
unit 32a Smith 3 d
```

or

```
Crescent, Johnsonville
```

i.e. I want to be matching on the last instance of:

```
 "[0-9][a-z] " or "[0-9] [a-z] "
```

I've tried:

```
var beforePattern = "^.*[0-9][a-z] ";
            var beforepatternSpace = "^.*[0-9] [a-z] ";
            var afterPattern = "[0-9][a-z] (.*)";
            var afterPatternSpace = "[0-9] [a-z] (.*)";
```

However the after patterns include the match string. Also, I'm unsure how to determine which before/after match should be used (apart from saying the longeest "before" or the shortest "after" must be valid)

Comment: Just hope you don't have any addresses in Edmonton Canada.  All the street names are numbers. So somebody's address might look like 123 121 St. W. This is probably a problem that will be very difficult to solve with just REGEX, as there are many different ways of writing addresses, and nobody follows any kind of standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use this in C#

```
(.*\d\s*[a-z])\s*(.*)
```

Group 1 & 2 have what you want now

Tested on both samples. Provide more examples if some cases are not expected.

Some C# code

```
var match = Regex.Match("unit 32a Smith 3 d Crescent, Johnsonville", @"(.*\d\s*[a-z])\s*(.*)");

var part1 = match.Groups[1].Value;
var part2 = match.Groups[2].Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var regex = new Regex( "(?<before>.*\d+\s?\w+\s)(?<after>.*)" );

var match = regex.Match( input );

var beforeString = match["before"].Value;
var afterString = match["after"].Value;
```

Since regex will match as much as possible this should find what you are looking for